# When I use the installer in swi-prolog to install the aleph, I got the ERROR: source_sink `path(git)' does not exist

Tags: prolog, aleph-ilp

When I am trying to install aleph into swiprolog, I got the errors as follow. Did I do something wrong?

```
?- pack_install(aleph).
% Contacting server at http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/query ... ok
Install aleph@5 from GIT at https://github.com/friguzzi/aleph.git Y/n? 
ERROR: source_sink `path(git)' does not exist
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [21] throw(error(existence_error(source_sink,...),_6768))
ERROR:   [17] process:process_create(path(git), 
[clone,'https://github.com/friguzzi/aleph.git'|...],[stdout(...),...|...]) at 
c:/prolog/swipl/library/process.pl:242
ERROR:   [16] <meta call>
ERROR:   [15] '$sig_atomic'(prolog_pack:process_create(...,...,...)) 
<foreign>
ERROR:   [14] 
......
```

Comment: Do you have git installed on your computer? Kind of looks like it was trying to run git and failed.

Comment: I already addressed this issue in a comment in your previous related question